# List of objects plus a tag

Tags: .net, generics

I want to store a list of objects, lets say of type Car, but with an additional 'tag' property eg a boolean True/False which does not belong on the Car class.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I need to pass the result between methods.

Comment: Does each Car need a tag? Or does the collection of Cars need a tag?

Comment: How do you want the tag to behave?  Do you want to get cars from the list by tag?  Would you want to get a Car/Tag pair form the list and deal with each pair individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tuple of some sort, like `Pair<T,U>`.

Heres an exemple:

```
namespace TestProject.Utils
{
    public class Pair<T, U>
    {    
        public Pair(T first, U second)
        {
            this.First = first;
            this.Second = second;
        }

        public T First { get; set; }
        public U Second { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For C#4, here's a good read about tuple : [CLR Inside Out - Building Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx)

EDIT : Usage

```
Car mustang;
List<Pair<Car, bool>> list = new List<Pair<Car, bool>>(); // <Car, isAwesome> pairs..
list.Add(new Pair(mustang, true));
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but...if I'm retrieving the list of cars then want to append the tag afterwards, I'll have to convert objects from one kind of list to another.  And I already have to do this again later.  Is it bad practice to be converting lists or this a common scenario?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<Car, bool> carFlags = new Dictionary<Car, bool>();
```

You can pass the car into the dictionary and get back the bool flag.

Answer (score 0):

Using inheritance, you can create a CarWithTag class that extends the Car class without polluting the Car class with unneeded properties:

```
public class Car
{
    public string CarInfoEtcetera { get; set; }
}

public class CarWithTag : Car
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a method that accepts a CarWithTag object when you need to pass tag info as well.

```
    private string GetCarTagInfo(CarWithTag car)
    {
        return car.Tag;
    }
```

Now you can new up a CarWithTag object and pass it into the method, along with any Car info.

```
        CarWithTag carWithTag = new CarWithTag()
                                    {
                                        Tag = "123abc", 
                                        CarInfoEtcetera = "etc"
                                    };

        string tag = GetCarTagInfo(carWithTag);
```